# Generated docx file is corrupted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, openxml, docx

I have a legacy Rails app, that can generate docx file. It's using just xml template, not any gem. Template is written using ERB syntax.

The problem is that generated file is marked as "corrupted" by MS Office Word, though LibreOffice on Linux opens it flawlessly. However, after recovering MS Office Word seems to open file without any content losses too.

I paste full XML template on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/C3QqrkFy).

While debugging I found out, that without the block, starting on the line 602, everything works fine. So I can't get, what's wrong with that particular piece of XML. I'll paste it right here for convenience

```
<% [task[:design_front], task[:design_back]].compact.each do |img_data| %>

            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                <w:noProof />
                <w:sz w:val="18" />
                <w:szCs w:val="18" />
                <w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:drawing>
                <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
                  <wp:extent cx="<%= img_data[:width] * 7400 %>" cy="<%= img_data[:height] * 7400 %>" />
                  <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0" />
                  <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="0" />
                  </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                  <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                      <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                        <pic:nvPicPr>
                          <pic:cNvPicPr>
                            <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="0" noChangeArrowheads="0" />
                          </pic:cNvPicPr>
                        </pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:blipFill>
                          <a:blip r:embed="<%= img_data[:id] %>" cstate="print">
                            <a:extLst>
                              <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" />
                              </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                          </a:blip>
                        </pic:blipFill>
                        <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                          <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                            <a:ext cx="<%= img_data[:width] * 7400 %>" cy="<%= img_data[:width] * 7400 %>" />
                          </a:xfrm>
                          <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst />
                          </a:prstGeom>
                          <a:noFill />
                          <a:ln>
                            <a:noFill />
                          </a:ln>
                        </pic:spPr>
                      </pic:pic>
                    </a:graphicData>
                  </a:graphic>
                </wp:inline>
              </w:drawing>
            </w:r>

          <% end %>
```

I tried to compare recovered file with my file, but I didn't see any crucial differences. I don't have that diff right now, but I can reproduce it if necessary.

Can someone show me the way? :) What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I tried to make corrections, suggested by Martin P., but no luck. Here is a diff between my generated file and recovered version (recovered on the right)

[image: Diff screenshot]

Comment: I found that some invalid unicode escape sequences can ruin the file. Check if your generated xml files contain `\uXXXX` in them. (where X is hex digit, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of debugging the answer is found.

The last part of this puzzle was the file `[Content_Types].xml`. It contained the line `<Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg" />`, but my images have `.jpg` extension. I changed `Extension` attribute to `jpg` and error was gone.

However, the additions suggested by Martin P. are necessary too (how can I credit him by the way?), because without them the resulting file remains corrupted, but with an another error message.

Thanks to everybody, who tried to help me. I hope, this answer will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you are missing two element and some attributes.

(1) The `wp:inline` needs to have a `wp:docPr` element containing an `id`, `name`, and `descr` attribute.

```
<wp:docPr id="<% id %>" name="<% picture_name %>" descr="<% full_file_path_to_the_picture %>"/>
```

(2) The `pic:nvPicPr` element needs to have a `pic:cNvPr` element containing the same attributes.

```
<pic:cNvPr id="<% id %>" name="<% picture_name %>" descr="<% full_file_path_to_the_picture %>"/>
```

Of course you have to insert the missing variables (`<% .. %>`).

Here I marked the line where to insert the elements using comments:

```
<% [task[:design_front], task[:design_back]].compact.each do |img_data| %>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                <w:noProof />
                <w:sz w:val="18" />
                <w:szCs w:val="18" />
                <w:lang w:eastAsia="ru-RU" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:drawing>
                <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
                  <wp:extent cx="<%= img_data[:width] * 7400 %>" cy="<%= img_data[:height] * 7400 %>" />
                  <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0" />
<!-- insert wp:docPr here -->
                  <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="0" />
                  </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                  <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                      <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                        <pic:nvPicPr>
                          <pic:cNvPicPr>
<!-- insert pic:cNvPr here -->
                            <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="0" noChangeArrowheads="0" />
                          </pic:cNvPicPr>
                        </pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:blipFill>
                          <a:blip r:embed="<%= img_data[:id] %>" cstate="print">
                            <a:extLst>
                              <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" />
                              </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                          </a:blip>
                        </pic:blipFill>
                        <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                          <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                            <a:ext cx="<%= img_data[:width] * 7400 %>" cy="<%= img_data[:width] * 7400 %>" />
                          </a:xfrm>
                          <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst />
                          </a:prstGeom>
                          <a:noFill />
                          <a:ln>
                            <a:noFill />
                          </a:ln>
                        </pic:spPr>
                      </pic:pic>
                    </a:graphicData>
                  </a:graphic>
                </wp:inline>
              </w:drawing>
            </w:r>

          <% end %>
```

If you look at your diff, you may see those elements added.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the problem is still there. I updated original question.

Comment: It looks like it add the two attribues `wp14:anchorId` and `wp14:editId` to the `wp:inline` element. It would add them in the template too using the values from the recovered element. And change the `r:embed` attribute value on the `a:blip` element from the image name to a value also like in the recovered file. All other changes don't seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that MS Office Word replaced the value of `r:embed` suggests that there was no definition of `@Id="image_1"` in the relationships file of this document. The relevant relationships file is probably `word/_rels/document.xml.rels`.